How to access the last 10 rows and first two columns of a DataFrame
I was given a file to practice pandas on, and was asked this question:
Q: Access the last 10 rows and the first two columns of the index dataframe.
So, I tried this code:
df = index[(index.tail(10)) & (index.iloc[:, :2])]
df

but it gave me an error. How do I access the last 10 rows and first two columns of a dataframe?
I expected to have the last 10 rows of the first two columns in a variable.

One way is to try with .iloc
df = index.iloc[-10: , :2]


-10: takes last 10 rows. Note the negative and look more into how iloc (section Indexing both axes).
:2 after comma takes first two column i.e. 0 and 1.


Here is how to do it using tail.
result = index.tail(10).iloc[:, :2]

.tail(10): Returns the last 10 rows of the DataFrame
.iloc[:, :2]: Selects all rows (:) but only the first two columns (:2)

Another method would be using individual indexers. This allows for more precise indexing; say you needed the last ten elements from two random columns in the dataframe:
Access via individual numeric indexers:
df.iloc[-10:, [idx1, idx2]]

Access via individual column names:
df.loc[-10:, ["col1", "col2"]]

Hope this helps.

"Access via individual column names" didn't work with me:
df3 = df1.iloc[-10: , ['A', 'B']]
IndexError: .iloc requires numeric indexers, got ['A' 'B']

You have to use "loc" instead of "iloc" to access via individual column names.
